# Visual Web Part control for select user/group?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-web-part

Does somebody know exist a control for a visualwebpart that allows to select an user/control?

I am creating a form using a visual web part and i want to allow to select an user.

I am searching for this control:

[image]

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's the PeopleEditor control. [Here](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/peopleeditor-control/)'s the good article about it. It's about 2007 version but there's no changes in 2010.

Answer (score 4):

To add the normal people picker to a web part you can use

`Microsoft.SharePoint.UserControls.PeopleEditor` or

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="myPeoplePicker" runat="server" Width="300" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1" />
```

Check out the below link, it has complete code:

http://salaudeen.blogspot.in/2012/04/using-people-picker-in-web-parts.html

Answer (score -2):

http://sharepointbyte.com/how-to-call-a-people-picker-in-visual-web-part-in-sharepoint-4/

Check out the above link, it has complete code:

Comment: Please donot provide only the links to the answer, kindly try to get the idea and put it on your own words here. so that it will be like adding more credit to this site rather than navigating to another site for answer.